# Getting report of unjoinable records from table when joining attributes by field value in QGIS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, attribute-joins, table, reports

I am working on a "Join attributes by field value" processing, but I would like to get the "unjoined" records from the table, not those from the vector layer, and if it's possible, to get a report in html as we can get from the vector layer using Grass tools.

Is there any expression that we can set or a Python code to do so?

[image: The red highlighted means that we can get info from the SHP but not from Tables (yellow)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running the tool again, but this time put the table as your first layer, and the joined results as the second layer.

Then you'll get the table records that are not present in the joined layer.

You can skip output under 'Joined layer' in the toolbox options, and generate a temporary or saved layer for the unjoinable features. You could save it as a csv and then do what you want with it (including exporting to an html table).

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much!